# Как обработать нажатия в настройках

Tags: android

В androidstudio сформировал шаблон настроек. По аналогии с шаблоном добавил свой файл настроек

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Preference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="pref_clear_know"
        android:summary="@string/pref_description_clear_know"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_clear_know" />
    <Preference
        android:key="pref_clear_learn"
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:summary="@string/pref_description_clear_learn"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_clear_learn" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Просьба помочь с кодом в этом месте, как обработать нажатие, чтобы словить текущее состоянии и дать новое?

```
private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {

        String stringValue = value.toString();

        if (preference instanceof Preference) {         




        }

        return true;
    }

};
```

вот пример как реализовано с ListPreference

```
if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
            // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
            // the preference's 'entries' list.
            ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
            int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);

            // Set the summary to reflect the new value.
            preference.setSummary(
                    index >= 0
                            ? listPreference.getEntries()[index]
                            : null);

        }
```

Comment: Этот колбэк реагирует на изменения значений в настройках, чтобы вы могли принять незамедлительные меры (если требуется), когда какие то параметры изменились. Он не предназначен для чтения или записи значений в настройки. Смотрите [сюда](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/preferences_framework.php) как работать с Preference.

Comment: ну приблизительно это понимаю, но как тогда инициализировать эти поля с xml файла в этом колбэке?

Comment: `preference.setSummary(stringValue);` - пропишите это в после  if (preference instanceof Preference) {     По крайней мере у меня по дефолту так было.

Comment: Как например сделано с ListPreference там же в примере

Comment: Что именно вам нужно сделать: немедленно отреагировать на изменение какой-то настройки или просто получить текущее значение в определенном месте. Вносятся изменения в настройки без вашего участия, то есть вы нажали на чекбокс в настройках - все, его новое состояние записалось, больше ничего делать не надо.

Comment: `preference.setSummary(stringValue);` не оказывает никакого эффекта, проверяю в классе `AppCompatPreferenceActivity` в методе `onPostResume()` выводя в лог все настройки  `SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Log.d("LOG_pref_1", String.valueOf(sp.getAll()));`

Comment: @pavlofff да хотелось бы сразу отреагировать на нажатие и выполнить метод по нему.

Comment: @pavlofff Пользователь заходит в настройки, там есть несколько "папок" или "headers" заходя в один из них он видит два (у меня так) пункта меню, которые отрабатывают только нажатие, без вывода дополнительных окон, вот мне вот эти нажатия  и булевые значения нужно отловить. Буду очень признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы незамедлительно отреагировать на **изменение** какой-либо настройки в активити\фрагменте требуется зарегистрировать колбэк на прослушивание, собственно, настроек.
Данный колбэк возвращает экземпляр самих настроек и ключ - имя той настройки, значение которой было изменено.

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
   }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
         if (key.equals("pref_clear_know")) {
             // действие при изменении настройки с ключом "pref_clear_know"

             // Получаем текущее значение настройки с ключом "pref_clear_know". 
             // true - значение по умолчанию,
             // если текущее считать не удалось или такой настройки не существует
             boolean clear = prefs.getBoolean("pref_clear_know", true);
          };

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {

    prefs.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Так же, если немедленного действия на изменение настройки не требуется, а нужно только получить текущее значение, то регистрировать слушатель нет нужды:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
            boolean clear = prefs.getBoolean("pref_clear_know", true);
}
```

Предпринимать специальные действия для записи в файл настроек не требуется. Значения запоминаются без участия программиста, в момент их изменения в окне настроек, но вы все же можете и записать свое значение, если есть такая необходимость:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("pref_clear_know", false);
    editor.apply();
```

**UPD**

Для того, чтобы **обработать нажатие** на элемент `<Preference>` без каких-либо контролов внутри, нам нужно зарегистрировать слушатель на клики ( а не на изменения значений):

*Предупреждение: в данном варианте могут потребоваться дополнительные действия по определению, какой пункт был кликнут в сложных экранах настройки*

```
public class MyPreferences extends Activity implements OnPreferenceClickListener {

   @Override
   public boolean onPreferenceClick (Preference preference){
   String key = preference.getKey();
   if (key.equals("pref_clear_know")) {
   // действие при клике на пункт настройки с ключом "pref_clear_know"
   }
}
```

Реакция данного колбэка будет происходить в момент нажатия на пункт в меню.

Так же вы можете повесить слушатель непосредственно на какой-то пункт списка. Данный способ должен работать без проблем для кликов на выбранном пункте - для этого слушатель нужно регистрировать в `PreferenceActivity`:

```
public class MyPreferences extends PreferenceActivity {

   Preference clear= findPreference("pref_clear_know");
   clear.setOnPreferenceClickListener((new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        // Действие при клике на пункт "pref_clear_know"
      }
   });

}
```

подробнее и другие варианты смотрите [этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15536908) на enSO

Comment: я сейчас задам глупый вопрос, но просто не понимаю, а вот в этом коде, который я приводил выше, достаточно будет сделать так и все будет работать:   `@Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
            String stringValue = value.toString();

            if (preference instanceof Preference) {
                preference.setSummary(stringValue);
            }`

Comment: Ну пробуйте, откуда я знаю, что у вас будет :)

Comment: попробовал и нет результата, (((

Comment: Что ж, это неожиданно, так как у меня все отлично работает.

Comment: если не трудно, можно ссылку на ваш пример, я окончательно запутался

Comment: разобрался все типы преференсы отрабатывают, кроме нужного мне пункта меню где нет никаких окон выбора и чекбоксов только сам пункт меню, который реагирует на нажатие `<Preference
            android:key="pref_key_clear_know"
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:summary="@string/pref_description_clear_know"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_clear_know"> </Preference>`